# Location of Opera cookies set to expire after restart (time 0)

Tags: opera, cookies

Where does Opera store cookies that are destroyed or expire after the browser is restarted?

I'm looking for information on where these temporary cookies, with time expire (0), and that are deleted after a browser restart.

I tested a file "cookies4.dat" using a hex editor and it doesn't have the temporary cookies stored inside.

Does Opera create a temporary file for these cookies and delete them after restart? If that was so, where are they?

Or does it store them in RAM?

Answer (score 2):

Opera stores cookies in memory, and commits persistent cookies every now and then to disk. Session cookies, or cookies with "0" as expire time is not written to disk at all.

Comment: Any source for this information? I'm curious.

Comment: I'm a Opera Software employee, and the answer is my understanding of the relevant documentation and source code. (disclamer; I'm not a browser developer, and the code base is large. There might be things I have overlooked)

Comment: thank you for details. Enjoy your stay on this site, there are occasionally some Opera questions which would require an "insider" answer.